# Google Maps API & Michael Jaspers JQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

I've been using Micheal Jaspers excellent JQuery & HTML code for years on a number of websites [convert address tags into Google Map](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2011/convert-address-tags-into-google-map-link-using-jquery/)

Here is Michael's HTML code

```
<address>
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500
</address>
```

And here is Michael's JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Convert address tags to google map links - Copyright Michael Jasper 2011
    $('address').each(function () {
        var link = "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent( $(this).text() ) + "' target='_blank'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>";
        $(this).html(link);
    });
});
```

His code is really user friendly, and easy to implement in a Dynamic PHP application - as he says the user only has to enter the correct address.  I am worried that given now Google is insisting that everyone has an API, and that keyless API map use will no longer function, my applications will no longer render the maps properly.

What is happening as a result of this code is that what is loaded is an embed map direct from Google Maps in an IFrame, and technically they are still free.

I was not able to upvote @xomena's answer but he is correct. I confirm as it is after the 16th of July, that there are no problems with using this code if you simply want to embed a map on your website, or generate it website wide if required for multiple addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that links used in your examples are not related to Google Maps APIs. You create links or iframes with URL of consumer application that is a separate product and doesn't have anything that requires an API key.

The API key are applicable for [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide), [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide), [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) or [Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro), but in your example none of these APIs is involved.

You don't need to include any API in your code in order to open the Google Maps web site link.

Also, I would suggest changing the links to use documented and supported [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide). Note that Google Maps URLs doesn't require an API key neither.

I hope my answer addresses your doubt!